# Analyze using world traffic service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, traffic, arcgis-10.7

I want to analyze using world traffic service. There are several points on the map. From these points, the process of determining the area that can go for 15 minutes by car will be made. How can I do this? I use ArcGIS World Traffic Service.
[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. It seems like [Service Area Analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) may be what you're looking for.